# How to get ACRID via ACRCloud API knowing the ISRC?

Tags: acrcloud

According to ACRCloud, they provide the ability to get songs metadata and links: https://console.acrcloud.com/metadata-links

So, knowing the ACRID, for example, we can find the ISRC via their Metadata API: https://docs.acrcloud.com/metadata/music

The question is: How to get ACRID if we know the ISRC?

Is it possible to do with help of ACRCloud API? Or what other method ACRCloud can provide? I couldn't find anything except the actual audio recognition.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get acrid with this API, you can only get it with the audio recognition, why do you need acrid?

Comment: Tony Li, thanks for your answer. I want to use ACRID as unique identifier in integration with my backend. I need it for both custom files and music from the ACRCloud music library

Comment: any possibility to add such kind of feature to ACRCloud API?

Comment: Why do you need to have acrid?

Comment: I answered in previous comment, will just copy it here again: I want to use ACRID as unique identifier in integration with my backend. I need it for both custom files and music from the ACRCloud music library